# 64 Bit ANE for iOS 8 backwards compatibility

Tags: ios, apache-flex, air, compatibility, ane

im trying to create a simple ANE to exend my Flex Application.

I Followed this tutorial to accomplish this Task:
http://www.lorenzonuvoletta.com/how-to-create-your-own-ane-for-ios-using-adobe-air/

I compliled my native lib with iOS 8.1 SDK, because i have read in some Blocks that i should to support the 64bit restiction from Apple.

I changed the plattformoptions.xml to the following (figured out, that a minimum sdk of 4.0 is not longer supported):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<platform xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/air/extension/3.7">
    <sdkVersion>8.1</sdkVersion>
    <linkerOptions>
        <option>-ios_version_min 6.1</option>
    </linkerOptions>
</platform>
```

My ANE works fine under iOS 8.1, but when i try to use it in the same test-app with a iOS 7.1.1 device, i get the following error:

```
[Fault] exception, information=VerifyError: Error #1014: Class de.hoermann.ast.eemawe.ane.nativeAlert::ANENativeAlert could not be found.
```

I compiled the App with Flex SDK 4.14.0 and AIR Runtime 16.

How can i support older iOS Versions than 8.1?

I've already set the iOS Deployment Target in Xcode to 4.3 and tried to compile the native lib with iOS 7.1 SDK.

After 2 days of searching and testing i got stuck on this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okey i finally found a solution to that probelem! :)

This error is caused by a bug in the AIR 16 runtime. 
When the Application uses a ANE and runs on a 64 bit device with iOS 7.x.

Compiling the Application with AIR 17 (Beta) fixes the problem.

Air Betas can be found here: http://labs.adobe.com/downloads/air.html 
(When you are using the Flex SDK, make shure to download the AIR SDK for Flex Developers)

I hope i can help others whith this post, who have similar problems.